# Remove duplicate <div> and </div> tags from a given string

Tags: c#, string, tags

I have the following string with several useless `<div>` and `</div>` tags.

```
<div style="xpto">
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div style="xpto">
               <div>
                  <div>
                     <div style="xpto">
                        <div>
                           <div></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I get into the following string, using c#, where there are no useless `<div>` and it's correspondent `</div>`

```
<div style="xpto">
   <div>
      <div style="xpto">
         <div>
            <div style="xpto">
               <div></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Now I'm trying to use span<t> to do the job. I'll post here if I got any success. My last try was using recursive function, but got stackoverflow when the input string is bigger than the sample i posted in my original question.